# Is it possible to simulate a minimal GPU inside a VM?

Tags: graphics-card, virtual-machine, gpu

I want to play a 1995 game inside a virtual machine. I only have one GPU, which is from my i7, but this GPU is being used by the main machine, so I cannot put it inside the VM. Is there a way to create a virtual GPU inside the VM to run this game? It has very low graphics necessities so I think it should be possible

I'm using virt-manager.

**UPDATE:**

it looks like virt-manager has some GPU features but I don't know how they work or couldn't ever make it work.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 it needs some very old directx but it works on newer ones. It even works on Windows 10. However, the game is from Steam, so I guess it'd be hard to switch its DLLs by these from SwiftShader. Also, I'd like to run it on linux with Wine. It works when I do it on my main linux machine, so it will work on a virtual machine with a virtual GPU

Comment: Steam won’t stop you from modifying most of a game’s contents. Also, why bother with Linux if you’re using a VM anyway?

Comment: Can you just add an old, cheap GPU and pass it through?  Even a throwaway GPU from 15 years ago will be ***way*** more powerful than a 3D card from 1995

Comment: i7’s don’t support VT-d which is required in a case like this.

Comment: @Keltari because it's a notebook. It supports external GPUs but I need it to be mobile

Comment: @Ramhound _Some_ I7's don't support VT-d (case in point: I have two that do support VT-d in systems on my desk right now), but they're actually pretty rare.  If the system doesn't have VT-d support, it's more often the baseboard these days, not the CPU.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Have you tried the various GPU settings offered by virt-manager?  If you can find the drivers, most of the paravirtualized GPU emulations should work fine for this (hint: many of the virt-manager backends can do the same GPU emulation as VMWare, which should be enough for an old DX1-4 game, and have readily available Windows drivers).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn where do I access these options in virt-manager? I thought it was in the video options where I had to choose between virtio and others. If it's this option, then I never managed to get my game working with more than 5fps. Do I have to do anythig more?

Comment: We need more info about your computer and problem. I don't understand why your GPU is not available for the VM, or does the game require specific hardware? Some info about the game will also help.

Comment: ... and which virtualization product : VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V?

Comment: @harrymc it's Worms Armageddon from 1999. When I run it inside a VM it's like at 5fps. I tried all the virt-manager video cards and all them gave the same lag. My GPU is not available for the VM because it's being used by the main system (I only have the on board GPU from intel)

Comment: @harrymc and it's virt-manager with QEMU

Comment: I understand you are on Linux and are using a virtual machine of Windows. There are many reports of slow graphics on QEMU,where the usual remedy is to use VNC or RDP, reported to give better results. The other solution of using [SPICE+QXL](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/SPICE) for faster graphics does not work for a Windows guest. You could also try to use other vitualization software than QEMU.

Comment: @harrymc I was actually using ubuntu with wine. I never tested on windows

Comment: @harrymc I'm using spice in the display and QXL. I'm downloading windows to try now

Comment: @harrymc even with windows, spice and QXL it won't go fast enough. Same as ubuntu

Comment: As said above: SPICE+QXL do not work for a Windows guest. For Wine, performance was never a target. VirtualBox might work better, but for real performance you would need to dual-boot with Windows, which is not the easiest configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different hypervisor. Try VirtualBox.

For DOS games you should use DOSBox:

```
sudo apt-get install dosbox
```

Answer (score 0):

For playing Worms Armageddon on Linux, you could have a look at the article named, emm...
[Play Worms Armageddon on Linux](http://worms2d.info/Play_Worms_Armageddon_on_Linux):

> In details, this program can be seen as a wine wrapper. It wraps a
>   wine1.0 version, that is **heavily patched with the purpose to run fine
>   with Worms Armageddon**.
>
> In better words, Play Worms Armageddon on Linux is a pure frontend
>   using several programs as its backend, these programs are wine1.0,
>   mount, ln ,rm and every windows tool you run with it (e.g Intes
>   Keychanger, Worms Armageddon and also Worms World Party).
>
> This makes it possible that you dont need to worry about your own wine
>   installation or wine at all. I builded some binarys (they include
>   everything you need to run Worms), these binarys are known to run on
>   Opensuse and Ubuntu without the need to compile something alone. But
>   you can also get the complete source of it, if problems occur with
>   these binarys.

The software can be downloaded from
[this page](http://lookias.worms2d.info/download.php).